# Drawing on canvas with coffee script

Tags: canvas, scope, coffeescript

I have two files

### tools.coffee

```
tools = {}

tools.pencil = =>
  @.started = false

  @.mousedown = (e) =>
    c.begin()
    c.moveTo(e._x, e._y)
    @.started = true

  @.mousemove = (e) =>
    if @.started
      c.lineTo(e._x, e._y)
      c.stroke()

  @.mouseup = (e) =>
    if @.started
      @.started = false
```

### script.coffee

```
find_position = (obj) ->
  curleft = 0
  curtop = 0
  curleft = $(obj).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft()
  curtop = $(obj).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
  { x: curleft, y: curtop };

init = ->
  window.canvas = $('#drawn').get(0)
  c = canvas.getContext('2d')
  c.lineJoin = "round";
  c.lineCap = "round";
  c.strokeStyle = "#"+ghex;
  c.lineWidth = 1;
  tool = tools.pencil
  $('#container canvas').bind('mousedown mousemove mouseup', mouse_draw);

mouse_draw = (e) ->
  position = find_position(this)
  e._x = e.clientX - position.x;
  e._y = e.clientY - position.y;
  func = tool[e.type];
  console.log tools
  tools.pencil(e)

$(window).ready =>
  init()
```

The point of the code is to draw on a canvas element if you cannot tell. I have been trying to get this to work for the past couple days off and on and I have not gotten very far.  The things I have learned are,

`tools.pencil` is defined but no methods of pencil are. I cannot figure out why that is.

Thanks for the help I think it just has to do with the scoping built into coffeescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is this line:

```
tools.pencil = =>
  ...
```

The "fat arrow" binds the function to the current value of `this`. That'll be the global scope.

Using the "thin arrow" (`->`) won't do function binding, so should lead to the expected result.

You might however consider something like this instead:

```
class Pencil
  started: false
  mousedown: (e) -> ...
  ... etc

tools =
  pencil: new Pencil()
```